# Ben ish chai vs shulchan aruch

Tags: halacha, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, shulchan-aruch, minhagim, ben-ish-chai

Are there any examples of Halachic questions where the Ben ish Chai “disagrees” with the shulchan aruch? Like I would imagine due to time and geography there may have been some questions answered in the ben ish chai that weren’t by the shulchan aruch, but are there any Halachas brought down in the shulchan aruch where the Ben ish chai actually disagrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many examples. In fact, Rav Ovadya Yosef z"l wrote an eight-volume critique of the Ben Ish Chai called [Halichot Olam](https://seforimcenter.com/Halichot-Olam---Rav-Ovadia-Yosef-8-vol.__p-6576.aspx). The main theme of Rav Ovadya's halachic writing is the obligation of Sefardim to follow the Bet Yosef, and he objected to the Ben Ish Chai's willingness to pasken against the Bet Yosef based on the writings of the Kabbalists.

[One](https://seforimcenter.com/showScannedImages.aspx?pfile=6576.jpg) example is that the Shulchan Aruch rules that if one forgot Retzeh in benching for the Seuda Shlishit, one does not repeat bentching. The Ben Ish Chai writes based on the Arizal that one should repeat bentching.